# Trying to install driftnet

Tags: centos

I'm trying to install driftnet. I think I've installed all the dependencies per the website but when I run make I get the error below.

```
makedepend -- -g -Wall -I/usr/include/pcap -D_BSD_SOURCE `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` -DDRIFTNET_VERSION='"0.1.6"' `cat endianness` -- audio.c mpeghdr.c gif.c img.c jpeg.c png.c driftnet.c image.c display.c playaudio.c connection.c media.c util.c http.c
cat: endianness: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: makedepend: command not found
make: *** [depend] Error 127
```

What have I done wrong? Is there something similar but more current?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just install the driftnet RPM? You don't say what OS you are running so this assumes RHEL5 or equivalent.

Install Howto

Download the latest rpmforge-release rpm from

http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/

Install rpmforge-release rpm:

```
rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release*rpm
```

Install driftnet rpm package:

```
yum install driftnet
```

Comment: I'm running centos 6.2 I don't think its in the repo? No package driftnet* available.
Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 2):

You don't have all the packages:

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/makedepend
imake-1.0.2-3
```

So, `yum install imake`.  I ran that on a CentOS 5 box, so the exact imake version may be different.

Comment: Thanks I made a bit more progress but now I have makedepend: warning:  display.c (reading /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstrfuncs.h, line 34): cannot find include file "stdarg.h"
Thanks

Comment: That's part of the `gcc` package.

Comment: Hmm.  You might be short of "build essentials".  Do a `yum install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel`.  You may need to install other *-devel packages also.

Comment: As per dmourati, you may also want to look at installing driftnet by package.  http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=driftnet  There doesn't appear to be RHEL6 version.  You might be able to get away with a recent Fedora RPM.

Comment: I've got the devel stuff installed. Did group install development tools thanksrpm -qa | grep gcc gcc-gfortran-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
gcc-c++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
gcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

The makefile appears to be in transition.  It creates an executable ./endian, which it uses to create endianness.h.  The `cat endianness` looks like it isn't needed anymore.  So I removed it from the Makefile and that let me proceed to my next problem.